# Azure AD B2C - CORS Policy Issue for Multi App Services

Tags: azure, cors, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I've 2 projects: **Project1** is main app (*localhost:4016*) **Project2** is child app (*localhost:4055*) and sharing authorization token cookies between 2 projects.

It's working fine locally but not working while hosted on Azure. Getting following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://devplatform.b2clogin.com/devplatform.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sign_in/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=XXXX&redirect_uri=https://myapps.example.com/home/index ...' (redirected from 'https://www.example.com/api/home/getlist') from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I'm using following OpenIdConnect for Azure AD B2C Authentication in multiple projects.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
    // Required for Azure webapps, as by default they force TLS 1.2 and this project attempts 1.0
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() {
        //locally it'll keep redirecting infinitely
        CookieDomain = ".example.com" //only required when we host it to keep persist cookies
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
        // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
        MetadataAddress = String.Format(Globals.WellKnownMetadata, Globals.Tenant, Globals.DefaultPolicy),

        // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
        ClientId = Globals.ClientId,
        RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,

        // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
            AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
            AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
        },

        // Specify the claim type that specifies the Name property.
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
            NameClaimType = "name",
            ValidateIssuer = false
        },

        // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
        Scope = $"openid profile offline_access {Globals.ReadTasksScope} {Globals.WriteTasksScope}"
        }
    );
}
```

If I do redirection on authentication failed event, get the nonce error as follows:

> IDX21323: RequireNonce is ‘[PII is hidden by default. Set the
>   ‘ShowPII’ flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]’.
>   OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null,
>   OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The
>   nonce cannot be validated. If you don’t need to check the nonce, set
>   OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to ‘false’. Note if a
>   ‘nonce’ is found it will be evaluated.

I can disable it by following statement:

```
ProtocolValidator = new OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator() { RequireNonce = false }
```

But it introduced following error:

> IDX21329: RequireState is '[PII is hidden]' but the
>   OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.State is null. State cannot be
>   validated.

I tried to disable that by following statement but still same issue.

```
ProtocolValidator = new OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator() { RequireNonce = false, RequireState = false }
```

Comment: Azure AD B2C DO NOT allow CROS in b2clogin.com domain.  Be sure that for customize UI, you need to enable CROS to customized html. It mean that CROS enable accessing from b2clogin.com domain to owned html. Here's an overview of what B2C uses [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization)

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity Thanks for your info. General issue is `Website 1` setup with the Login - Authentication. `Website 2` doesn't getting authentication tokens and hence redirecting to b2clogin.com domain. However, same coding and settings works locally.

Comment: you have cors issue so it doesnt look like it is related to your auth settings. you have custom ui ? where do you host your custom ui ?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, custom ui for login. It's working locally. I've 2 AD: `directory1` for app and `directory2` for app services where I host my apps. Structure here: https://www.screencast.com/t/KFpFUKFp2G

Comment: But where do you host your custom ui files ? in blob storage ? did you enable cors on your storage account ?

Comment: @Thomas yes, in blob storage and cors is enabled. From where do you want me to confirm to make sure we're discussing same?

Comment: Could you check that `'https://devplatform.b2clogin.com/` is listed in the storage cors policy ?

Comment: @Thomas, it wasn't there but I tried adding there and checked still same issue.

Comment: what is your cors configuration ? from which dns/url are you trying to access the storage account ?

Comment: Any luck on this? I have the exact same issue and I do not have the custom HTML pages deployed in storage. I am also getting IDX21329 error complaining about the state.

Comment: @GirishAcharya For me only solution worked is msal.js library. Not sure but I'd to perform many patches on it.